# Scala "takes no type parameters, expected: one" when using type parameters

Tags: scala, generics, types

I would like to write a method that operates on subtypes of maps of a value to a traversable. My first attempt was to define it as:

```
def m[A, B, T[B] <: Traversable[B], M[A, T[B]] <: collection.Map[A, T[B]]](m: M[A, T[B]]): M[A, T[B]]
```

However, this definition gives me the following type errors:

```
T[B] takes no type parameters, expected: one
  def m[A, B, T[B] <: Traversable[B], M[A, T[B]] <: collection.Map[A, T[B]]](m: M[A, T[B]]): M[A, T[B]] = {
                                                                                              ^
```

and

```
T[B] takes no type parameters, expected: one
  def m[A, B, T[B] <: Traversable[B], M[A, T[B]] <: collection.Map[A, T[B]]](m: M[A, T[B]]): M[A, T[B]] = {
                                                                                 ^
```

I don't see any difference between the definition of `T[B] <: Traversable[B]` and `M[A, T[B]] <: M[A, T[B]]`, except for one more level of type parameters.

I get the same error when I parametrize `M` with another type parameter:

```
def m[A, B, C, T[B] <: Traversable[B], M[C, T[C]] <: collection.Map[C, T[C]]](m: M[C, T[C]]): M[C, T[C]]
```

If I change the signature to

```
def m[A, B, T[B] <: Traversable[B], M <: collection.Map[A, T[B]]](m: M): M
```

and remove the type parameters from `M`, compile errors disappear. Can anyone explain to me what's the problem with the first version?

The last version compiles, but gives type errors at call site, so I guess the type parameters should be provided somehow. For example

```
val map = mutable.Map.empty[Int, Set[Int]]
m(map)
```

gives

```
inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Set[Int]]] do not conform to method m's type parameter bounds [A,B,T[B] <: Traversable[B],M <: scala.collection.Map[A,T[B]]]
  m(map)
   ^
```

Comment: Gah I'm almost certain that you running into this is [my fault](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4f8c9b7b-86e6-42bd-a9fc-7775d8204f52/view-source) :(. I was really bad in the previous answer I gave you and labeled the `A`s without realizing that the `A` that comes before the arguments is only necessary for the `S[A]` in the argument itself and that I had been shadowing the type variable of `A` in `S[A]`. I'm in the middle of editing my other answer and am really sorry about confusing you!

Comment: @badcook I'm pretty sure that SO is like rolls of the dice, where events are independent and it's more or less random whether a given question or answer is well-informed. Please rest easy tonight.

Comment: @badcook don't worry about it! I learned something good about Scala in these two days :-)

Comment: @som-snytt I do hope that the dice of my answers are very biased... Oh well, a humbling experience that one can always make mistakes and to be circumspect about not passing on those mistakes to others. Time to up that bias towards correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A type bound like `T[B] <: Traverable[B]` shouldn't refer to other type parameters. Rather, `B` is meant to be a "free" parameter. You should replace it with another symbol, like `T[X] <: Traverable[X]`. You also don't need to require that `M[A, T[B]] <: Map[A, T[B]]` exactly, because `T[B]` is already bound elsewhere. You can replace it with `M[Y, Z] <: Map[Y, Z]`.

```
def m[A, B, T[X] <: Traversable[X], M[Y, Z] <: collection.Map[Y, Z]](m: M[A, T[B]]): M[A, T[B]] = m

scala> m(collection.mutable.Map.empty[Int, Set[Int]])
res6: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Set[Int]] = Map() // correctly inferred

scala> m(collection.mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]) // fails to conform
<console>:12: error: no type parameters for method m: (m: M[A,T[B]])M[A,T[B]] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int])
```

Comment: Thanks! let me ask you a follow up question. Why doesn't  the Scala compiler warn me about reusing a type parameter? does it shadow it? Is there any case where a type parameter such as [A,T[A]] will be useful?

Comment: Or `T[_] <: Traversable[_]`, is that right? I shudder to refresh my memory.

Comment: @som-snytt I don't think `T[_] <: Traversable[_]` will do what you want. I'm pretty sure that you get an existential type on the right-hand side instead (\*crosses fingers that I got at least this right\*).

Comment: For instance `def f[A, B, C[_] <: Traversable[_], M[Y, Z] <: Map[Y, Z]](m: M[A, C[B]])(p: (A, C[B])): Map[A, C[B]] = m + p`

Comment: @som-snytt Right, but you won't actually able to isolate `B` from `C[B]` within the body of the function; you can only use `B` if you specialize `f` at its call-site (and thereby effectively ignore the existential). For example, `def f[A, B, C[_] <: Traversable[_], M[Y, Z] <: Map[Y, Z]](m: M[A, C[B]])(p: (A, C[B])): B = (m + p).values.head.head` will fail to typecheck. Or maybe more simply, `def doThis[A, C[_] <: Traversable[_]](x: C[A]): A = x.head` won't typecheck either. On the other hand `def doThat[A, C[X] <: Traversable[X]](x: C[A]): A = x.head` compiles just fine.